# SearchList doesn't work for my project

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to do a search in my list and i used search list example in docs.sencha.com , but search functionality doesn't search.

I write the code in view after i define searchfield.

```
    xtype: 'textfield',
       docked: 'top',
       placeHolder: 'Arama...',
       //autoCapitalize: true,
       //  label: 'Anahtar Kelime',
       labelWidth: '`',
       listeners : {
              scope.this,
              keyup : function(field) {         
                      var value = field.getValue();
                      if (!value) {
                           Menius.filterBy(function()  {
                                 return true;
                           };
                      } ;                                            
                      else {
                           var searches = value.split(' '),
                           regexps = [],
                           i;
                           for(i=0; i< searches.lenght; i++) {
                                  if(!searches[i])
                                        return;
                                  regexps.push(new RegExp(searches[i], 'i'));
                           };
                          Menius.filterBy(function(record){
                          var matched = [];
                          for(i=0; i<regexps.lenght; i++) {
                              var search = regexps[i];
                              if (record.get('label').match(search))  
                                    matched.push(true);
                              else matched.push(false);
                          };


                         if (regexps.length > 1 && matched.indexOf(false) != -1)  {
                                return false;
                         } else {
                                return matched[0];
                         }
                   });
                 }
        }
```

What i want to do is when i type something into the searchfield , list must be filtered according to that word.

Answer (score 0):

Because of spelling mistake,

Change from

```
lenght -> length
```

in both the for loops.

[image]